# clearInterval not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm using javascript **setInterval** function to make some queries to a server but when the unload method is trigged the GETs are not stopping.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    example.init();
});

$(window).unload(function(){
    clearInterval(example.INTERVAL_ID_1);
    alert(example.INTERVAL_ID_1+" killed!");
});

var example= {

    init: function(){
               this.INTERVAL_ID_1;

               ...
               this.INTERVAL_ID_1 = setInterval(function(){     
                ...
            }, 9000);

        },
        ...
}
```

The unload method is called, the alert gives the right INTERVAL_ID but it stays alive, I can see the queries being made in the server console.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the interval on the `onbeforeunload` event?

Comment: The server console does not seem to be the right debugger. Add `console.trace()` in that function and look in the browser's console.

Comment: Shouldn't all intervals be stopped on-Unloading a page anyway?

Comment: I'm with @Bergi and have to wonder how you know the interval is still running, since the window unloaded...?

Comment: If page unloaded it cannot send any request! Only if page is refreshed and new loaded page (maybe with same URL) starts to send requests.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it's working... it's strange sometimes the server console is flooded with GET and POST, but now it's working... strange.

Thanks though ;)